# Chrome Extension: Javascript works in browser, but not as extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

http://jsbin.com/ejofazU/1/

Works find in the browser, but when I make it a popup chrome extension, the javascript doesn't work, and don't know why. Source is still the same, I attached content scripts in the manifest thinking that would help, but still can't seem to get this to work.

Any help is much appreciated.

**Manifest**

```
{
   "name": "Resistor Color Calculator",
   "description": "Just a basic resistor color calculator.",
   "version": "1.1.0",
   "permissions": [
     "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"
   ],
   "icons": {
     "128": "src/128x128.png",
     "256": "src/logo.png",
     "48": "src/48x48.png"
   },
   "browser_action": {
     "default_title": "Resistor Calculator",
     "default_icon": "src/48x48.png",
     "default_popup": "popup.html"
   },
   "content_scripts": [
     {
      "matches": ["http://*/*"],
      "js": ["jquery.js"]
     }
   ],
   "manifest_version": 2
}
```

**Popup**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
body {
   margin:0; padding:0;
   width: 600px; height: 500px;
   background:#000;
}
/* Styles Table/Text */
table {
   position:absolute;
   top:80px; left:0;
   width:100%; height:100%;
   font-weight: bold; color: gray; background: black;
}

/* Table Header */
th { text-align: center; color: white; background: #0af; }

/* Table Data */
td { background: white; }

/* Calculation */
h1 {
   position:absolute;
   top:0px; left:0;
   width:100%; color: white; text-align: center;
}

/* Calculation Area */
input { width:0; height:0; padding:0; margin:0; visibility:hidden; position:absolute; top:-100000; left:-100000; }
h1 {
   position:absolute;
   top:0px; left:0;
   width:100%; color: white; text-align: center;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function generation() {
   // Colors
    $("select#colors").each(function() {
      var color = $(this).val();
      if(!color)
         return;
      $('span#1').text(color);   
    });

   $("select#digits").each(function() {
      var digits = $(this).val();
      if(!digits)
         return;
      $('span#2').text(digits);
   });

   $("select#multi").each(function() {
      var multi = $(this).val();
      if(!multi)
         return;
      $('span#3').text(multi);
   });

   $("select#toller").each(function() {
      var tollerance = $(this).val();
      if(!tollerance)
         return;
      $('span#4').text(tollerance);
   });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
   generation();

   var opt1 = $('#1').text(),
      opt2 = $('#2').text(),
      opt3 = $('#3').text(),
      opt4 = $('#banswer').text(),
      problem = $('input[name=problem]'),
      answer = $('input[name=hideresult]');

   problem.val(opt1 + '' + opt2 + '' + opt3);
   answer.val(problem.val());
   answer.val(eval(problem.val()));
   $('#answer').text(answer.val());
});

$(document).change(function(){
   generation();

   var opt1 = $('#1').text(),
      opt2 = $('#2').text(),
      opt3 = $('#3').text(),
      opt4 = $('#banswer').text(),
      problem = $('input[name=problem]'),
      answer = $('input[name=hideresult]');

   problem.val(opt1 + '' + opt2 + '' + opt3);
   answer.val(eval(problem.val()));
   $('#answer').text(answer.val());
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <!-- Calulation Result -->
   <div id="genarea">
      <h1 id="genresult">
         <span id="1"></span><span id="2"></span><span id="3"></span><span id="banswer"> = </span><span id="answer"> answer </span><span id="e-answer">&ohm;</span> <span id="4"></span><span id="math"></span>
      </h1>

      <input type="text" name="problem" />
      <input type="text" name="hideresult" />
   </div>

   <!-- Resistor Color Chart Here -->
   <table>
      <tr>
         <th>
            <select id="colors">
               <option value=" ">1st Band</option>
               <option style="background:black; color:white;" value="0">Black</option>
               <option style="background:brown; color:white;" value="1">Brown</option>
               <option style="background:red; color:white;" value="2">Red</option>
               <option style="background:orange; color:white;" value="3">Orange</option>
               <option style="background:yellow; color:black;" value="4">Yellow</option>
               <option style="background:green; color:white;" value="5">Green</option>
               <option style="background:blue; color:white;" value="6">Blue</option>
               <option style="background:violet; color:black;" value="7">Violet</option>
               <option style="background:grey; color:white;" value="8">Grey</option>
               <option style="background:white; color:black;" value="9">White</option>
            </select>
         </th>
         <th>
            <select id="digits">
               <option  value=" ">2nd Band</option>
               <option style="background:black; color:white;" value="0">Black</option>
               <option style="background:brown; color:white;" value="1">Brown</option>
               <option style="background:red; color:white;" value="2">Red</option>
               <option style="background:orange; color:white;" value="3">Orange</option>
               <option style="background:yellow; color:black;" value="4">Yellow</option>
               <option style="background:green; color:white;" value="5">Green</option>
               <option style="background:blue; color:white;" value="6">Blue</option>
               <option style="background:violet; color:black;" value="7">Violet</option>
               <option style="background:grey; color:white;" value="8">Grey</option>
               <option style="background:white; color:black;" value="9">White</option>
            </select>
         </th>
         <th>
            <select id="multi">
               <option value=" ">3rd Band</option>
               <option style="background:black; color:white;" value="*1">x1</option>
               <option style="background:brown; color:white;" value="*10">x10</option>
               <option style="background:red; color:white;" value="*100">x100</option>
               <option style="background:orange; color:white;" value="*1000">x1,000</option>
               <option style="background:yellow; color:black;" value="*10000">x10,000</option>
               <option style="background:green; color:white;" value="*100000">x100,000</option>
               <option style="background:blue; color:white;" value="*1000000">x1,000,000</option>
               <option style="background:violet; color:black;" value="*10000000">x10,000,000</option>
               <option style="background:grey; color:white;" value="*100000000">x100,000,000</option>
               <option style="background:white; color:black;" value="*1000000000">x1,000,000,000</option>
               <option style="background:white; color:black;" value="/10">&divide;10</option>
               <option style="background:white; color:black;" value="/100">&divide;100</option>
            </select>
         </th>
         <th>
            <select id="toller">
               <option value=" ">4th Band</option>
               <option style="background:Black; color:white;" value="&#177; 1%">Black</option>
               <option style="background:Brown; color:white;" value="&#177; 2%">Brown</option>
               <option style="background:Gold; color:black;" value="&#177; 5%">Gold</option>
               <option style="background:Silver; color:black;" value="&#177; 10%">Silver</option>
               <option value="&#177; 20%">None</option>
            </select>
         </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th>Color</th>
         <th>Digits</th>
         <th>Multiplier</th>
         <th>Tollerance</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th style="background:black;">Black</th>
         <td>0</td>
         <td>x1</td>
         <td>1%</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th style="background:brown;">Brown</th>
         <td>1</td>
         <td>x10</td>
         <td>2%</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th style="background:red;">Red</th>
         <td>2</td>
         <td>x100</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th style="background:orange;">Orange</th>
         <td>3</td>
         <td>x1,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <th style="background:yellow; color:black;">Yellow</th>
         <td>4</td>
         <td>x10,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th style="background:green;">Green</th>
         <td>5</td>
         <td>x100,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th style="background:blue;">Blue</th>
         <td>6</td>
         <td>x1,000,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th style="background:violet; color:black;">Violet</th>
         <td>7</td>
         <td>x10,000,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th style="background:grey;">Grey</th>
         <td>8</td>
         <td>x100,000,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th style="background:white; color:black;">White</th>
         <td>9</td>
         <td>x1,000,000,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th style="background:gold; color:black;">Gold</th>
         <td></td>
         <td>&divide;10</td>
         <td>5%</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th style="background:silver; color:black;">Silver</th>
         <td></td>
         <td>&divide;100</td>
         <td>10%</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <th style="background:white; color:black;">None</th>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td>20%</td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not really a great description if you are looking for people to help you.

Comment: Without other information and debugging efforts from you my money is on PEBKAC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, please, go and read about **[SSCCE](http://sscce.org)**.

---

According to the docs on **[changes regarding Manifest V2](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_migration_to_manifest_v2.html#inline_scripts)**:

> [...] inline event handlers [...] will not execute.
>
> These will not work in manifest V2 extensions. Remove the inline event handlers, place them in your external JS file and use addEventListener() to register event handlers for them instead.

So, in your case, move any code inside `script` tags in a JS file and reference that file as the `script`'s src. Also, replace any inline JS with equivalent code in the external JS file (e.g. adding event-listeners).